# Are all subsets of $X$ $m$-measurable for $m(A):=\inf\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty\text{diam}(C_i):A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty C_i,C_i\subset X\}$?

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

A measure theory book I am reading, *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions, 2nd ed., pp. 34*, seems to have a bit wonky definition for the one dimensional Lebesgue measure:

$$\mathcal{L}^1(A):=\inf\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty\text{diam}(C_i):A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty C_i,C_i\subset \mathbb{R}\}$$

The authors do not seem to impose any restriction for the sets $C_i\subset\mathbb{R}$ while the definitions of the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$ I have seen so far use e.g. closed/open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$. This raises the question that if we are in a metric space $(X,d)$ and define

$$m(A):=\inf\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty\text{diam}(C_i):A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty C_i,C_i\subset X\}$$

where the $C_i$s are allowed to be any subsets of $X$, are then all subsets of $X$ $m$-measurable?

Answer (score 1):

Allowing for infinity as a possibility, the infimum always exists, so to that extent the measure $m(A)$ can always be defined. This is not the same as allowing all sets to be measurable -- the contradictions arise when you start imposing axioms on your measure space, e.g. additivity.

As for allowing arbitrary subsets $C_i$, this is an unusual approach but I don't think it changes anything. By allowing arbitrary $C_i$, it might seem that the Lebesgue measure can decrease, as you are taking the infimum over a larger set of covers. However, I claim that for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can replace an arbitrary cover with a cover using open/closed intervals and only increase the total sum of the diameters by $\epsilon$, so taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ you end up with the same infimum, and hence the same measure. Can you fill in the details here? (Hint: use an $\epsilon/2^n$ trick)

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I am seeing the full picture of the proof and need help when any $C_i$ is closed/not open or closed:

Let us use for a second definition of the Lebesgue measure $\tilde{L}$ the dyadic subcubes of $\mathbb{R}$ (it's not too hard to show that this gives the standard Lebesgue). Then given an arbitrary cover of $C_i$s, all open $C_i$s can be partitioned by countably many dyadic subcubes with disjoint interiors.

But when a $C_i$ is not connect (i.e. not an interval) and it is either closed or not open or closed, I am not sure how to partition/cover such $C_i$ appropriately.

Comment: You don’t need to partition the sets. Just cover them with intervals with slightly bigger diameter.

Comment: Do we take an inteval $I_n$ for $C_n$ such that $\text{diam}(I_n)=\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}+\text{diam}(C_n)$ with $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $s:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\text{diam}(C_n)<\epsilon+\mathcal{L}(A)$? This then gives that $\tilde{\mathcal{L}}(A)\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\text{diam}(I_n) = \epsilon+s<2\epsilon+\mathcal{L}(A)$ whence the reverse inequality.

Comment: Yes, but make sure that the interval contains the set C.